# How to use app services in imported razor class library components

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor-webassembly, razor-class-library

I have created a rcl razor class library and referenced it in my web assembly app.

The articles on the web discuss how to import static assets used in rcl to the main app.

But if the imported rcl component wants to use a service or a class from the webassembly app I want to know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If they need to be shared, move them from your App's main project into their own Razor Class Library. Then you will be able to share them.